# Single Dialog for edit - change object on render - React Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

so I got a dialog using `React-Modal` like this:

```
var React = require('react'),
    ptypes = React.PropTypes;
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var $ = require('jquery');

var VehiclePlantDialog = React.createClass({
    PropTypes: {
        vehiclePlant: ptypes.object
    },
    openModal: function (vehiclePlant) {
        this.props.vehiclePlant = vehiclePlant;
        console.log(vehiclePlant);
        this.props.openModal();
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log(this.props.vehiclePlant);
        return (
            <div className="modalLayout">
                <form>
                    <input ref="inputText" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                    <button onClick={this.props.closeModal}>Cancel</button>
                </form> 
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = VehiclePlantDialog;
```

This works fine but now when I hook this up to a table, I'm creating 1 modal per item right?

Table row:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Modal = require('react-modal');
var $ = require('jquery');
var VehiclePlantDialog = require('./VehiclePlantDialog.jsx');
const customStyles = {
    content: {
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        right: 'auto',
        bottom: 'auto',
        marginRight: '-50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
    }
};

var VehiclePlantRow = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { modalIsOpen: false };
    },
    openModal: function () {
        console.log("set state open");
        this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
    },
    afterOpenModal: function () {
    },
    closeModal: function () {
        this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {  
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <tr key={this.props.plant.id}>
                <td>{this.props.plant.code}</td>
                <td>{this.props.plant.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.plant.createdAt}</td>
                <td>{this.props.plant.expiresAt}</td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.plant.isExport == 0 ? 'No' : 'Yes'}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={this.openModal}>Edit</button>
                    <Modal
                        isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                        onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
                        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
                        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
                        style={customStyles} >
                        <VehiclePlantDialog openModal={this.openModal} closeDialog={this.closeModal} plant={this.props.plant}/>
                    </Modal>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = VehiclePlantRow;
```

How can I make sure to create just one Modal and change the object when I'm opening said Modal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you have the modal in the wrong location.  It should exist in the parent component that is rendering the entire table.

For each row, pass a function to it as a prop;

```
<VehiclePlantRow onSelect={this.onSelect}/>
```

And then after the table, include the modal identically to how you currently have it, but reference the plantfrom state, rather than props;

```
<VehiclePlantDialog openModal={this.openModal} closeDialog={this.closeModal} plant={this.state.plant}/>
```

And create the onSelect function;

```
onSelect: function(plant){
    this.setState({plant: plant, modalIsOpen: true});
}
```

Within `VehiclePlantRow`, replace your existing onClick function to reference the parent function passed in as a prop;

```
<button onClick={this.props.onSelect.bind(this, this.props.plant)}>Edit</button>
```

Move the rest of your modal related functions to the parent component as well, and you should be all set.

Comment: Just finished this, awesome man thank you! It is working like a charm. Sidenote to your solution though, when calling `bind` coming from the props (not from `this` itself), you need to pass `null` as first parameter for some security reasons it seems (React stuff). `this.props.onSelect.bind(null, this.props.plant)`. Accepted and upvoted your answer. Thank a bunch! it took me a while.